# destruct object with interface

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, javascript-objects, object-destructuring

I have this code:

`const {items} = this.props;`

but, I need to set the interface into the `items` constant

and I do not want to do this:

`const items: ItemsInterface = this.props.items`

Possible?

Comment: Have you tried to let your component extend `React.Component<{items: ItemsInterface, ..}>`? That should infer the correct type for `this.props.items`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Oblosys stated in his comment, the preferred approach should be to destructure a well typed source object and rely on type inference.

Type annotation syntax interacts awkwardly with and inconveniently with the destructuring syntax.

Still, if you really wish to ascribe a type in the destructuring expression, there are a few ways.

1. The simplest is to apply a type assertion to the right hand side of the expression

   ```
   const {items} = <{items: ItemsInterface}>this.props;
   ```

   Or equivalently

   ```
   const {items} = this.props as {items: ItemsInterface};
   ```

   Of course this is verbose, but it is clear, correct, and obvious.
2. Perhaps closer to your instinct, you can specify the type of the destructuring expression with a type annotation as you would any other.

   ```
   const {items}: {items: ItemsInterface} = this.props;
   ```

   I personally find this awkward and a bit hard to read. The type annotation being ascribed to the unnamed expression `{items}`.
3. If you are ***incidentally*** specifying a default value in the destructuring expression, you can actually specify the type inline.

   ```
   const {items = <ItemsInterface>{}} = this.props;
   ```

Or equivalently

```
    const {items = {} as ItemsInterface} = this.props;
```

In any case, there is no way to avoid repeating the name `items` unless you are initializing with a default value.

I prefer the first option, since it is cleaner to alter the type of an existing value, here `this.props`, with an *assertion* applied to that value than to add a type *annotation* to the receiving declaration, here `items`, since the latter offers no intuition to the reader that the type is being manually adjusted.